# How to make slideDown() work in ajaxForm() on THE FIRST execution of live('click')

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidedown, preventdefault, ajaxform

For this particular problem i usually use preventDefault(); but in this case it doesn't work. I would be thankful if anyone helps me with this one. Here is some of my code:

```
            $('.place_order').live('click',function(){
                        $('#place_order_form').ajaxForm(function(){ 
                        $('#shopping_cart').slideDown(150,function(){

                        $('#shopping_cart').load('url here');

                        $('#shopping_cart').css('display','block');
                        $('#shopping_cart').css('height','290');

                        });
                        }).submit();
            });
```

It works fine after slideUp() is executed, but on first click it just loads the data without slideDown. Any help is appreciated because I am noob Jquery developer.

Comment: What version of jQuery, `live()` was removed in newer versions, and deprecated long ago ?

Comment: jQuery JavaScript Library v1.9.1.
Note that this same code works. The problem is that when you first click place order the shopping cart just shows, but not slide down. if you hide it and click order again it works.

Comment: `live()` was removed in 1.9, use the delegated version of `on()` instead. If you do a search on Stack Overflow you'll find a gazillion answers on how to use `on()`.

Comment: thank you for this information, but the code works fine. the problem is slideDown() doesnt work on the first click. It works on the next clicks though.

Comment: you either don't have any content, as that is added with ajax later, or the element you're trying to slide is hidden, see my answer!

Comment: adeneo, content is shown and everything works fine. only slideDown doesn't work when first clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this :

```
$(document).on('click', '.place_order', function(){
    $('#place_order_form').ajaxForm(function(){ 
        $('#shopping_cart').hide().load('url here', function() {
            $(this).slideDown(150);
        });
    }).submit();
});
```

Comment: On the first click the content is loaded without slide down. on more clicks content is also loaded but with slideDown.

Comment: It should work like that, and I have no way of testing the ajaxForm plugin right now, so I really don't know what the issue is ?

Comment: This works! It solved my problem. I think what did the job was the hide() function.
Sorry i said this didn't work but i copied it wrong at first.